# unexpected result from augmented assignment to association

Tags: core-language, associations, assignment

Is the last of these results expected?  If so, how?

```
assoc=<|"a"->1,"b"->2|>;
assoc["a"]+=1;
assoc (* <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|> *)
assoc[[{"a","b"}]]=1;
assoc  (* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1|> *)
assoc[[{"a","b"}]]+=1;
assoc  (* <|"a" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>|> *)
```

**Edit:**

Kuba helpfully points out that this reflects the behavior of `Part`, specifically

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
assoc[[{"a", "b"}]]  (* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> *)
```

Unfortunately, this pushes my question back to the behavior of `Part`.  We are told by the docs that `Part[expr,i]` gives the `i`th part of `expr` and that `Part[expr,{i1,i2,…}]` gives a list of the parts i1, i2, … of `expr`.  This seems to imply that

```
Part[expr, {i1,i2,...}]==(Part[expr,#]&/@{i1,i2,...})
```

But this is clearly not the case for associations.  E.g.,

```
assoc[[#]] & /@ {"a", "b"}     (* {1,2} *)
```

How am I misreading the docs?

Comment: `Part` is given special instructions for some atomic objects, like sparse arrays and associations, but they don't directly return the specified parts of the underlying data structure.  It was apparently decided that the benefit of this behavior outweighed the inconsistency it introduces.

Comment: About the edit, take a look at  ref / Part / Generalizations and Extensions examples. That is expected but yes, wording could be improved. Feel free to ask WRI support.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, I see what you mean.  Even after your pointing me to it for rereading, I find that wording very far from clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not at the first sight but it is expected once you think more about this.

```
 assoc[[{"a", "b"}]] +=1
```

is

```
assoc[[{"a", "b"}]] = (assoc[[{"a", "b"}]] + 1 )
```

and while *rhs* operation is still ok, the following one is not defined for associations (not counting generic assignment to values):

```
assoc[[{"a", "b"}]] = <|"a" -> 2, "b" ->3|>
```

in case of `Lists` only dimensions play a role for threading but here keys too. There are `Merge` and friends for this kind of operations and by default it will just treat it as a single element *rhs* case, assigning association to each value.

Trace also makes sense:

```
assoc[[{"a", "b"}]] += 1; // Trace
```

> ```
> { assoc[[{a,b}]]+=1;
> , { assoc[[{a,b}]]+=1
> , { { assoc
>     , <|a->1,b->2|>
>     }
>   , <|a->1,b->2|>[[{a,b}]]
>   , <|a->1,b->2|>
>   }
> , { assoc[[{a,b}]]=<|a->2,b->3|>
>   , <|a->2,b->3|>
>   }
> , <|a->2,b->3|>
> }
> , Null
> }
> ```

Comment: I've elaborated my question in response to your comment.  (See the edit.)